# WPF Mvvm navigation with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation

Following [this tutorial](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) (among others) and reading questions asked here I've constructed a navigation mechanism that will allow me to pass parameters between my `ViewModels`:
**Object base - every view model inherits from it:**

```
public abstract class ObjectBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //INotifyPropertyChanged members
    ...

    //Navigation handling
    public abstract ObjectBase BackLocation { get; }

    public abstract event Action<ObjectBase> NavigateTo;

    public abstract string ViewHeader { get; }
}
```

**MainViewModel - in charge of navigation:**

```
public class MainViewModel : ObjectBase
{
    private ObjectBase _selectedView;
    private CommandBase _backCommand;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SelectedView = new FirstViewModel();
    }

    public ObjectBase SelectedView
    {
        get { return _selectedView; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedView, value);
            //register to the navigation event of the new view
             SelectedView.NavigateTo += (target)=> { SelectedView = target; };
        }
    }

    //This command is bound to a Back button on the main view
    public CommandBase BackCommand
    {
        get { return _backCommand ?? (_backCommand = new CommandBase(Back)); }
    }

    private void Back(object obj)
    {
        if (SelectedView.BackLocation != null)
        {
            SelectedView = SelectedView.BackLocation;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

**And the main view:**

```
<Window ...    
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FirstViewModel}">
        <views:FirstView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SecondViewModel}">
        <views:SecondView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedView}"/>
</Window>
```

My problem is: If I set the `DataTemplates` in the main view like the above it makes each view aware of it's `DataContext` so if I want to add the `DataContext` explicitly to a view in order to use intellisense like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Wpf_NavigationTest.Views.FirstView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Wpf_NavigationTest.ViewModels">
<!--this causes the view model's constructor to get called again-->
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:FirstViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="User control 1" FontSize="40"/>    
</Grid>
```

the `View Model's` constructor is called twice, losing the parameters passed by the `Navigate` event.

Comment: "*so if I want to add the `DataContext` explicitly to a view*" - Can you provide an example of how you are achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are setting the `DataContext` inside your `UserControl`, and also in your main view model.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:FirstViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

The code above is instantiating a **new** `FirstViewModel` every time this `UserControl` is created. Therefore when the control gets *created* by the `ContentControl` (based on the `DataTemplate`), it then goes ahead and also creates a new `FirstViewModel`.

So, the solution here is to remove the `UserControl.DataContext` declaration in the `UserControl`, and you can instead set the `DataContext` of the `ContentControl` to that of your `SelectedView`.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedView}"
                  DataContext="{Binding SelectedView}"/>
```

In order to use multiple view models to a single view, you can simply add another `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ThirdViewModel}">
    <views:SecondView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

For **Design-Time** data (to get the intellisense), you can make use of `d:DataContext` as explained in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn169081.aspx) article.

This will require you to set up some view models as static resources, I would recommend creating them in a separate `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: this doesn't let me use intellisense  when designing the user control (I guess that it's because the user control is not aware of him being inside the `ContentPresenter`)

Comment: I've edited my answer for further information on how to implement design-time data using `d:DataContext="..."`